# Possible ways of binding data in a Spring MVC Controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

What are the possible ways to bind data to method parameters of a Spring MVC controller other than @RequestBody and @ModelAttribute. Can i bind data using @Valid, implementing code like below.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/person", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createPerson(@Valid Person person, BindingResult bindingResult){
    ...
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? This question makes no sense as it is. State your motivation and someone may suggest a solution you haven't thought of.

Comment: Please be specific. Explain your question little more.

Comment: What do you mean by "How can this controller be called?". Its a post method so it will be called once you submit your page.

Comment: Yes bu without any of the annotations above(@RequestBody,@ModelAttribute)?

Comment: Your controller method is valid. You can invoke the method using an HTML form or any HTTP client libraries. Follow the URL for some sample code http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-jsr303-valid-example/

Answer (score 0):

If you are POSTing a model of Person with the form having a model attribute of "person", you could do::

```
public View postUser(@ModelAttribute("person") @Valid Person, BindingResult result)
```